# pcap_sendpacket fails with error "send:try again"

Tags: c, linux, ethernet, libpcap

I am trying to send packets using pcap_sendpacket api in a while loop and I was successfull at sending packets. I have added some sleep in between to control the rate of sending.

Now, if I remove the sleep and try to send as fast as I can, I am facing error in pcap_sendpacket api saying `"send: try again"` for half of the packets. I want to know why its failing exactly. Is there any way I can know more on this?

I checked the man pages and sendpackets returns -1 for error and with pcap_geterr I am getting above message. Return value of -1, doesn't say much about why its failing. I checked the pacp library but I was unable to see any such error message. How to proceed further on this?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to send packets faster than they can make it onto the network, on an operating system where the call used to send raw packets does *not* block if whatever buffer it's using is full and you try to send another packet.

You may have to insert short delays between `pcap_sendpacket()` calls.